# What is the default userid and password for airflow login through Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I've installed airflow through docker , Its asks me for userid and password.

Note - I've tried userid - airflow and pwd- airflow but no luck

Comment: Actually, requesting the base path (e.g. localhost 8080) you get redirected to the /admin path without being asked credentials and are given possibility to create users.
Have you tried a pre-packaged docker-compose.yml like this?
https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow

Answer (score 4):

You can try entering airflow default username and password and see if this helps.

The default username is: airflow
The default password is: airflow

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It's sound like you are missing [this step](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#initializing-environment):

```
echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0" > .env
```

Answer (score 1):

username: admin and password: admin worked for me. I used kind (for k8s)